# Can iOS 5 devices take advantage of new iOS 6 delegate methods?

Tags: ios

There is a new `UITableView` delegate method called something similar to `cellDidEndDisplaying` (like `willDisplayCell:`) which is called when a cell goes offscreen. This is in the new preview SDK. My question is, if I use this method, will it only work on iOS 6 devices, or iOS 5 as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is under Apple NDA.

That being said, methods are not backwards compatible - that is, if you used a new method in iOS 4, it would not work in iOS 3. Because in your case you are overriding a delegate method, your app will not crash - the method will simply not be called. If you wanted to call a new method that doesn't exist in a previous version of iOS yourself, you'd want to ask the object if it `respondsToSelector:` or if it's a new class, check if `NSClassFromString(@"MyClass")` is `nil`.